# Create 48 plots by iterating through columns of pandas dataframe - How to increase column index in a loop?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, loops, plot, indexing

I have a Pandas Dataframe with 96 columns x 100 rows which looks like this:

x1,   y1,   x2,    y2,   x3,    y3,  ..., x48,  y48

0.5,  521,  1.8,   625,  5.5,   856, ..., 2.5,  453

0.6,  556,  1.9,   695,  5.6,   1023, ..., 2.6,  569

I want to plot y1 against x1, then y2 against x2, y3 against x3, and so on.

I'm really struggling with increasing the column indices. This code doesn't work:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'xxx.csv', delimiter=';')

for col in df:
    x=col
    y=col+1
    df.plot(x, y)
    plt.show()
```

> TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

I get the problem, but don't know how to solve it :(

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach (*highly inspired by Trenton McKinney*).

We start by selecting/zipping the `x` columns and `y` columns with [`pandas.DataFrame.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) and [`pandas.DataFrame.columns`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.columns.html), then we use [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter.html) (feel free to put any other kind of plots).

Try this :

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# df = pd.read_csv(r'xxx.csv', delimiter=';')

combos = list(zip(df.filter(like="x").columns, df.filter(like="y").columns))

fig, axes = (
                plt.subplots(nrows=int(len(df.filter(like="x").columns)/2),
                             ncols=int(len(df.filter(like="y").columns)/2),
                             figsize=(8, 4))
            )

axes = axes.flat

for (x, y), ax in zip(combos, axes):
    ax.scatter(df[x], df[y])
    ax.set(title=f'{x} vs. {y}', xlabel=x, ylabel=y)
        
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

##### # Output :

[image]

##### # Used Input:

```
print(df)
    x1   y1   x2   y2   x3    y3  x48  y48
0  0.5  521  1.8  625  5.5   856  2.5  453
1  0.6  556  1.9  695  5.6  1023  2.6  569
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Can I save each of the 48 plots as a separate plot and not as subplots?